# Traceview — scroll not working

Tags: android, scroll, android-traceview

When running `Traceview` from command line a java UI appears.

My problem is that I can't scroll the views.

I see the orange scroll indicator but can't click on it in order to move it (a larger arrow box doesn't appear so I can't touch it and scroll the views).

Perhaps it's something with Ubuntu's (11.10) scroller?

Perhaps it's something with Swing?

Perhaps it's a combination with Swing and Ubuntu's relatively new scrollbar?

Comment: I found a workaround - using traceview from eclipse and not from the command line.

Comment: I think you can answer and accept yourself, to help other people reading your question.

Comment: It's a workaround, not an answer to the question